# iFrame error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm developing ASP .Net MVC project and for the first time I'm working with iFrame. In one folder I have the view in which I want to put the iFrame, and in another folder i heve the content that I want to put in the frame.

Here is the structure:

```
Project
  -Folder X
  -Folder X
  ...
  -Views
    -FolderX
      -HereIsTheiFrame.cshtml
    -FolderY
      -HereIsTheContentForiFrame.cshtml
```

This is what I tried:

```html
 <div>
     <iframe src="/Views/FolderY/HereIsTheContentForiFrame.cshtml">
     </iframe>
 </div>
```

But in the browser console i get error :

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

If I change it to `src="~/Views/FolderY/HereIsTheContentForiFrame.cshtml"` I get this error :

> GET https://localhost:44376/Views/FolderY/HereIsTheContentForiFrame.cshtml 404

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.net MVC does not allow you to serve .cshtml pages directly as it expects you to serve them via a controller.

Make sure you have the following in your web.config to allow it to serve .cshtml directly:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the direct link to "HereIsTheiFrame.cshtml" and to "HereIsTheContentForiFrame.cshtml"? I suspect it is without the /Views/ folder.

That should also be the url you put in the iFrame src.

Comment: What do you mean by "direct link"? The path for "HereIsTheiFrame.cshtml": C:\Folder1\Folder2\ProjectName\Views\FolderX\HereIsTheiFrame.cshtml; The path for "HereIsTheContentForiFramel":C:\Folder1\Folder2\ProjectName\Views\FolderY\HereIsTheContentForiFrame.cshtml;

Comment: The url you use in the browser, is it the following? 'https://localhost:44376/FolderY/HereIsTheContentForiFrame.cshtml'

Answer (score 0):

According to the error, I saw that it try to make a GET call:

> GET https://localhost:44376/Views/FolderY/HereIsTheContentForiFrame.cshtml 404

So I made an action that returns the view and it worked.

```
public IActionResult Load_iFrameAsync()
{
   var model = new MyModel();
   return View("~/Views/FolderY/HereIsTheContentForiFrame.cshtml",model);
}
```

```html
 <div>
     <iframe src="@Url.Action("Load_iFrame","MyControler")">
     </iframe>
 </div>
```